# Setting scroll indicator insets on NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I know `UIScrollView` has `scrollIndicatorInsets`, so if I had a `UICollectionView` I could do something like

```
collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
```

But how can I set the scroll indicator insets on an `NSCollectionView` since `NSScrollView` doesn't appear to have a `scrollIndicatorInsets` property?

Answer (score 1):

Collection view is enclosed in Clip view which itself enclosed in Scroll View which has the following:

```
collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.scrollerInsets
```

Which are declared:

```
/* The distance the scrollers are inset from the edge of the scroll view. */
@available(OSX 10.10, *)
public var scrollerInsets: NSEdgeInsets
```

You can also access the scroller object itself if you need futher customizations:

```
collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.verticalScroller
```